# PHP and PDO class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to learn OOP and decided to make a class which uses PDO.Here some codes from my class.

```
class DB extends PDO {

public function _construct($dsn,$user,$pass,$options=""){
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        try {
              parent::__construct($dsn, $user,$pass,$options);
              $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        }
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
              echo $e->getMessage();
         }
}


    public function run($query,$all="",$secure=""){
    if(empty($secure)){
        $qry=$this->query($query);
    }else{
        $qry=$this->prepare($query);
        $qry->execute($this->cleanup($secure));
    }
    if($all=="all"){
         return $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else{
         return $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}



private function cleanup($secure) {
    if(!is_array($secure)) {
        if(!empty($secure))
            $secure = array($secure);
        else
            $secure = array();
    }
    return $secure;
}

public function rowCount($table,$extra=""){
    $query="Select count(*) from ".$table;
    if(!empty($extra)){
        $query="Select count(*) from ".$table." ".$extra;
    }
    $qry=$this->query($query)->fetchColumn();
    return $qry;
}

public function select($table,$extra=""){
    $query="Select * from ".$table;
    if(!empty($extra)){
        $query="Select * from ".$table." ".$extra;
    }
    return  $this->query($query);
}


}
```

What is difference between following codes why i don't get the same result ?

```
//usage 1 (it doesnt work that way)
$return =$qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $return;

//usage 2 (it is exactly what i need but i want to learn the difference)
return $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Edit :** I realy don't know what I was doing wrong but it seems there is no difference between these usages.They both work now.

This is how I use my method

```
$result=$db->run("my query","all");
foreach($result as $r){
    //
}
```

In the construct method i use PDO's query method to set character to utf-8 but it does not work. If I use after created a DB object it works.

```
try {
    parent::__construct($dsn, $user,$pass,$options);
    $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
            $this->query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
}
```

last question

```
            //what do u think about this usage.I didnt run accross some thing like this
            //all the pdo classes i checked use it just 
            // return $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //do you think i need to separate "fetchAll"  and "fetch"
            if($all=="all"){
         return $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else{
         return $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: Before you learn OOP you should learn how to indent consistently

Comment: then i just need to learn how to do it in stackoverflow's editor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extend PDO it's just wrong in so many ways. You should instead use it like your title suggests

```
class Database
{
     protected $pdoInstance;

     public function __construct($pdoInstance)
     {
          $this->pdoInstance = $pdoInstance;
     }

     public function query($query)
     {
         $preparedStatement = $this->pdoInstance->prepare();
         /* bla bla bla */
     }
}
```

This code makes a lot more sense, and is a much better example of good object oriented programming. (It still makes me cringe however, but it's a good start)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, such a good questions can be rarely seen here.
Very few people understand the need of an abstraction class upon PDO.

So, here are some suggestions.

1. Don't make `run` into single function. it is much more convenient to have separate methods for different result types. Compare

   ```
   $data = $db->getAll($sql);
   $data = $db->run($sql,"all");

   $data = $db->getOne($sql);
   $data = $db->run($sql,"one");

   $data = $db->getCol($sql);
   $data = $db->run($sql,"col");
   ```
2. You need to think of the function names. Your "cleanup" function doesn't do any cleanup.
   I would use func_get_args() instead.
3. *What is difference between following codes why i don't get the same result ?*

   There is no difference

   ```
   $return = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $return;
   ```

   should work. Define "it doesnt work".
4. *In the construct method i use PDO's query method to set character to utf-8 but it does not work.*

   Although you should set charset in DSN, this one should be working too. Define "not working"
5. Also I would suggest to create DSN in the constructor, making config file more familiar.
   You may wish also to get some ideas from my [mysql helper class](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql). Though it is using different approach from prepared statements, it is way more secure than PDO

Comment: `$var =$othervar` is not a syntax error, but `$var $othervar` is .. am I confused?

Comment: Were you drunk while answering this question?

Comment: I have checked again 3th question and there was no difference as you said.Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: Double-indent for code in lists :) I took the liberty of cleaning it up, hope you don't mind